# how to get selected columns from OData source Table using azure data factory?

Tags: dataset, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, odata, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to get the selected column values from the OData source table using azure data factory with copy activity, but i got all the columns from the source table. i want only selected columns.

Comment: I'm not an Azure expert but OData allows you to specify what fields you want returned in _$select_ of your request.  Have you done that?

Comment: You can use **Query** option  in source dataset and give the query with  $select. Refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/concepts/queryoptions-overview#select)

Comment: Ok, for example in that Dataset query with ($select emp name, emp id from table name) is this right query, and how to write table name(ex- my OData table name is edm.employees)

Comment: $select is a comma delimited list of fields you want returned.  For more info, have a look [here](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) - specifically the section titled "4.8. Select System Query Option ($select)".

Comment: You can write the query like `/<entity-name>/$select <col1>,<col2>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Give the entity name in the path of the OData dataset.

[image]

- The example dataset has 3 columns. From these three columns, query is written to select only `name` and `lcaocode` fields.
- In source tab of copy activity, select Query option and enter `$select=Name,IcaoCode` in the query textbox.

[image]

- By this way, only required columns from OData source can be selected.

Comment: I got it, thankyou. Is there any chance to get two tables with different columns, i want selected columns from different tables so how can write query in that Dataset